# Why is the "My Work" Team Explorer widget not available in Visual Studio 2015 Professional?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I want to try out the integrated TFS code review functionality, which according to Microsoft documentation is available under the "My Work" widget in Team Explorer.

In previous versions of VS this feature was restricted to higher product tiers, but it is my understanding that in VS2015 they have loosened the restriction and this should be available with Professional.

I installed VS2015 Professional and see the same items in Team Explorer as in VS2013 - no "My Work" is to be found, and thus no code review. It appears there is no longer a standalone Team Explorer installer for 2015, so I'm not sure what else I need to do.

UPDATE:
There's conflicting documentation on this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx - "The My Work feature is available only in Visual Studio Premium and Visual Studio Ultimate" - this is presumably left over from previous versions - The "Premium" and "Ultimate" flavors no longer exist

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500420.aspx - "Other pages, such as My Work, are only available with Visual Studio Enterprise Edition"

Here is where I originally read that it should be available in Professional - https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3701106-make-code-review-available-to-professional-users

Answer (score 1):

Just tested in VS 2015 Professional Update2 (connect to TFS 2015.2), item "My Work" sits on Home page. Please make sure you have installed the latest patch. And please notice that "My Work" only exists in TFVC, not Git.

Also, "My Work" feature exists in  at least a TFS 2012 server.

Comment: I already have Update 2 installed, I'm not sure if there are any other updates I can install. The About window says: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2. Does the TFS installation on the server need to be 2015?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? I just made VS 2015 Professional Update2 to connect TFS 2013.5, item "My Work" still sat on Home page.

Comment: It turns out our server is still on 2010. I'm guessing 2012 is the minimum version required for this feature

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You need to connect to at least a TFS 2012 server in order to see the My Work page.